# Error when select from two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: `movie`, `actor` and `movie_actor_mapping`. And I wrote an query that select data from table movie and group actors for each movie. But after that I add another two tables `movie_player_episode_mapping` and `player` and I have to modify my query to select and group seasons that available for movie. For example, if table `movie_player_episode_mapping` contains seasons 1 and 2 for `movie_id = 1` I have to get string `1,2`.

So, my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` float(2,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `actor` (
  `actor_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `movie_actor_mapping` (
  `movie_actor_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_actor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `movie_actor_id` (`movie_actor_id`)
)
```

And my query:

```
SELECT title, group_concat(a.name separator ', ') as actors
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma ON m.movie_id = ma.movie_id
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = ma.actor_id
WHERE m.rating IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m. movie_id
ORDER BY m.rating DESC;
```

Another my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_player_episode_mapping` (
  `movie_id` int(11) UNSIGNED,
  `season` tinyint(11) UNSIGNED,
  `episode` tinyint(11) UNSIGNED,
  `player_id` tinyint(11) UNSIGNED,
  `path` TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE `player` (
  `player_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostname` VARCHAR(30),
  `name` VARCHAR(30),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);
```

I tried to modify my query like this:

```
SELECT title, group_concat(a.name separator ', ') as actors, group_concat(mpe.season separator ', ') as seasons
    FROM movie m, movie_player_episode_mapping mpe
    INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma ON m.movie_id = ma.movie_id
    INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = ma.actor_id
    WHERE m.rating IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY m. movie_id
    ORDER BY m.rating DESC;
```

But I've got an error: `[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'm.movie_id' in 'on clause'`.

I also tried next query but my result wrong. For example if my `movie_player_episode_mapping` contains for `movie_id=1` only rows for 1 season, I've got `seasons: "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1"` instead `seasons: "1"`

```
SELECT title, group_concat(a.name separator ', ') as actors, group_concat(mpe.season separator ', ') as seasons
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN movie_player_episode_mapping mpe ON m.movie_id = mpe.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma ON m.movie_id = ma.movie_id
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = ma.actor_id
WHERE m.rating IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m. movie_id
ORDER BY m.rating DESC;
```

Where is my mistake and how can I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, but are you _really_ sure that you get the posted error message when executing the last query you posted? A column `tv_id` is neither shown in your table creation, nor used in the queries.

Comment: Yeah. That error message relates to a different query. Anyway, don't use comma join syntax. And especially, NEVER mix syntaxes.

Comment: @arkascha I am sorry, I edited my error message

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, edited my error message. I am novice in databases, can you say me which way is better than join, please?

Comment: Some other observations: The 10 in INT(10) is meaningless, as is the 11 in TINYINT!! and   `rating` wants to be DECIMAL.

Comment: Explicit JOINs (JOIN y ON y.id = x.id) are good. Implicit joins (FROM x, y WHERE...) are bad. Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs is disastrous

Comment: @Strawberry oh, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, group_concat(a.name separator ', ') as actors, group_concat(mpe.season separator ', ') as seasons
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma ON m.movie_id = ma.movie_id
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = ma.actor_id, movie_player_episode_mapping, mpe
WHERE m.rating IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m. movie_id
ORDER BY m.rating DESC;
```

may be this can help you...your last query

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, but  if my `movie_player_episode_mapping` contains for `movie_id=1` only rows for 1 season, I've got seasons: "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1" instead seasons: "1"